# How to partition export of all the Service Principals in an AAD tenant?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We need to export information about all the Service Principals of an AAD tenant periodically. We expect the number to be large so we need to partition the export. When exporting users from Microsoft Graph we were able to partition based on first letter of `mailNickname` using `startswith(mailNickname, '<letter>')` as filter but trying that on `appId` and `id` with ServicePrincipals errored out with `Request_UnsupportedQuery`. Is there another way we could use to parallelize data export?

Ex of request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=accountEnabled eq true and startswith(appId, '0')&$select=id,appId,displayName&$top=999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting is similar to the approach I shared here (feel free to experiment with that code):

https://github.com/piotrci/Microsoft-Graph-Efficient-Operations/blob/master/Microsoft-Graph-Efficient-Operations/ScenarioImplementations/UserScenarios.cs

Filtering on ids is usually not supported by Graph resources. I my short experiment, I was able to use servicePrincipal's displayName to partition the collection.

Note however, that such approach is not guarantee uniform partitioning. Also, in your scenario (periodic full exports) is this optimization necessary?

Suggestion: consider using Graph's delta query to do a full export once, and then only pick up delta changes. This may be a much better optimization if you expect high volume, but limited churn to the resources.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/delta`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. Delta had a good number of limitations when dealing with Users, but the query for Service Principals is simpler so maybe good enough.